# Android to Android remote connection via Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, remote-access

I want to create an android app that can access another android device remotely and can also control that device by sharing screen. I talked with my professor about this and he said you cannot do it unless you have your device rooted. But I see Team Viewer Quick Support does the same thing without device being rooted. How do they do it?

There is very little documentation on this topic. Every topic or tutorial says about android to desktop connection. I am really confused about where should I begin. I tried JSch but it is not working and the only documentation (a code sample) given was not for Android Studio rather Eclipse.

Comment: One thing you can do maybe is using the MediaProjection new api, along with sockets for remote control (clicking, swiping events)

Comment: I checked MediaProjection. I am able to use screen capturing now and recording it as well, but clicking and swiping is not found yet

Comment: @JannatulFerdousSrabonee - Were you able to find or make such an app for non-rooted phones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android Studio comes with Java and Kotlin, you can use Jsch library to establish a connection to a remote SSH server with Java. Here is the sample code:

```
Session session = null;
ChannelExec channel = null;

try {
    session = new JSch().getSession(username, host, port);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.connect();
    
    channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    channel.setCommand(command);
    ByteArrayOutputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    channel.setOutputStream(responseStream);
    channel.connect();
    
    while (channel.isConnected()) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    
    String responseString = new String(responseStream.toByteArray());
    System.out.println(responseString);
} finally {
    if (session != null) {
        session.disconnect();
    }
    if (channel != null) {
        channel.disconnect();
    }
}
```

PS: I was able to implement this requirement and my app is running up in production!

Answer (score 0):

May be considered.

You can use `C++` or `C` with java by `JNI (Java Native Interface)`. Also note that you will need a server to make the connection between computers.

Like Teamviewer uses port `80` to make a connection to a central server. Once you run Teamviewer it's connect to their server and you get a unique id. Which you can share others to find your computer and authorized a remote connection with your computer after entering the password.

Comment: Should I use an X server for this? Can you describe a bit details about it please?

Comment: *Should I use an X server for this?* What do you mean?? @Jane